# Installing qemu-guest-agent on a redhat vm without internet access

Tags: rhel, kvm, qemu

I have a redhat 7.4 machine, and I'm installing a 7.2 VM on it. This isn't for production, 99.9% just for learning.

I've gotten the VM up and running, but now I'm trying to set up a qemu guest so that I can actually communicate with it. I'm following the instructions written out [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_deployment_and_administration_guide/chap-qemu_guest_agent#sect-QEMU_Guest_Agent-Set_Up_Communication_between_Guest_Agent_and_Host), but I'm encountering an issue when I get to step 3 of procedure 11.1. When I write

```
yum install qemu-guest-agent
```

I get the following error message:

```
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. 
You can use subscription-manager to register. 
There are no enabled repos. 
You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

I've tried following the instructions to enable repos with no success-- I get an error message informing me that I still need to register my product. Unfortunately, the host machine can't attach to the internet for security reasons (this is at my place of employment, so I have no means of changing that). So far as I can tell, I'll never be able to send anything to this VM except by flash drive (also not possible on the work machine) unless I can enable qemu operations.

How can I install qemu-guest-agent without registering the VM or getting internet access?

Comment: One method could be to add your `qemu-guest-agent` packages to whatever process you used to install the VM in the first place.  Another method could be to download a RedHat DVD ISO that matches your system, and then install the packages you need from that.  You really should make sure that your RedHat machines get proper licenses and subscriptions.  If you do not intend to get the proper licenses then you should be using CentOS instead.

Comment: Wouldn't I run into the same issue if I try to use CentOS? I still won't have internet access, so the installation of qemu wouldn't work, so far as I'm aware. I haven't been able to find any information on using VM manager to transfer files directly.

Comment: Have you tried using an installation DVD to install the packages you want (the DVDs contain the entire YUM repository for the distribution)?  I mentioned CentOS as you may not have access to the RedHat package DVDs without paying for a subscription.

Comment: Oh, that might work. I've been using the free-with-an-account ISO files that redhat provides on their website.